# jQuery queue

Tags: jquery, очередь

Как добиться очереди, чтобы `test` не аппендился во время анимации при множественном быстром клике?

```
​<div class="test">HIDE/SHOW</div><span></span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<button>button</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('button').click(function(){

    $('div').hide('slow');

    $('span').append('test <br />');

    $('div').queue(function(){

        $(this).show('slow');

    });

    $('div').dequeue();

});
```

**css**

```
​span {
 display: block;
position: absolute; top: 50px;
 width: 300px; height: 300px; background: #F7F7F7;   
}
button {
 position: absolute; z-index: 2;
bottom: 0;  
}
```

Весь прикол в том что когда много раз кликаешь кнопку, то в span аппендится текст, когда идет анимация, как это запретить, используя **queue**, а не флаги?

[test на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/sWfYy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Занести [всё в queue](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/sWfYy/1/).

[Update](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/sWfYy/2/). Добавил блокирование кнопки.

Comment: так оно выполняется, только в очереди. По моему таки флаги нужно ставить, мне нужно чтобы оно вообще не выполнялось. А только когда выполнилось уже можно было нажимать на кнопку.

Comment: тут только флагами.

Comment: @Maris, посмотрите мой update.